# Date only field one day off

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am taking date only field in ECMA script but while `set_item` stores the value one day off.

How to set it with the current selected date?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint expects the dates sent back to it via the Client Object Model to be in UTC time zone.

```
var isoDate = SP.TimeZone.localTimeToUTC(yourdatefield).toString();
 oListItem.set_item('date', isoDate);
```

This will set it with current selected date.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj246758%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Comment: I am using it in SharePoint 2010 and getting SP.TimeZone undefined

Comment: var tmpDate= new Date(yourDate);
tmpDate= tmpDate.toISOString();var isoDate = SP.TimeZone.localTimeToUTC(tmpDate).toString();
 oListItem.set_item('date', isoDate);

Comment: Thanks Anuja.But SP.TimeZone function is not available in 2010 it is only in 2013.

Comment: SP.RegionalSettings.timeZone

Comment: Thanks for quick reply but all is for SharePoint 2013.

Comment: opps yes, I think then you need to use getTimezoneOffset()

Comment: I tried with the below script but not worked. I am taking date only field.                                                          var addBrowserUtcOffset = function (date) {
    var utcOffsetMinutes = date.getTimezoneOffset();
    var newDate = new Date(date.getTime());
    newDate.setTime(newDate.getTime() - (utcOffsetMinutes*60*1000)+(8*60*1000));
    return newDate;
}

Comment: <script language="Javascript">
var now = new Date();
var utc = new Date(now.getTime() + now.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
alert(utc);
</script>
This will give you UTC convert date

Comment: Hi Anuja, Not worked.I am considering only date only field and it adds 00:00:00 time to it after converting it adds 18:30:00 to it and date remains same.